# Php, how to mock object instantiation?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

So, a function:

```
function testMe ($a, $b)
{
    $obj = new CalculationObject();
    return $obj->calcIt ($a, $b);
}
```

how to mock this creation?

Comment: maybe you can add how you usually "mock an object" in another language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactor the function to separate object creation and object usage.

If this is a method of a class, the trivial solution is to make `$obj` a class property so you can replace it with a mock.

If you always need a new instance of `CalculationObject`, the factory pattern can be used.

#### Example:

```
function testMe ($a, $b)
{
    $obj = $this->factory->getNewCalculationObject();
    return $obj->calcIt ($a, $b);
}
```

Then replace `$this->factory` with a stub that returns your mock for `getNewCalculationObject()`.

If this is really a procedural function, not a method, you need to pass the dependency to the function:

```
function testMe ($a, $b, $factory)
{
    $obj = $factory->getNewCalculationObject();
    return $obj->calcIt ($a, $b);
}
```

You could use the normal factory by default to make it backwards compatible to your current implementation:

```
function testMe ($a, $b, $factory = null)
{
    if ($factory === null) {
        $factory = new CalculationObjectFactory();
    }
    $obj = $factory->getNewCalculationObject();
    return $obj->calcIt ($a, $b);
}
```

If this looks a bit clumsy to you, consider moving the function into a class.

Comment: I see. So, in other words, no direct object creation BUT using factories?