# How can I replace A PHP class by PHPUnit stub?

Tags: phpunit, stub

Here is my function waiting for a phpunit's test:

```
<?php
class Dog
{
    public function born()
    {
        $a = new Action();
        $rs = $a->talk();
        return $rs;
    }
}
```

And the class Action is :

```
class Action
{
    public function talk()
    {
        return "true";
    }
}
```

The test function is :

```
public function testStub()
{
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('Action')
        ->getMock();
    $stub->method('talk')
        ->willReturn('false');
    var_dump($stub->talk()); // "false"

    $dog = new Dog();

    //[How can the born method invoke the stub method ?]
    var_dump($dog->born()); // "true" [I think it should be "false",but it isn't]
}
```

Now, How can I use the stub class to replace the class Action ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php, how to mock object instantiation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495360/php-how-to-mock-object-instantiation)

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is currently written you cannot replace `Action` with a test double. The code needs to be refactored so that you can inject `Action` instances. Then you can use a test double instead of a real `Action` instance.

Comment: Helpful ! Thanks a lot.